# Is there a way to use nikon lens with a sony nex 3n

Tags: lens, lens-adapter

I have a nikon d3200 and I want to use those lenses on a Sony nex 3n. Is there an adapter for this or it it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Sony Alpha NEX-3N uses the Sony E-Mount. So get the appropriate mount adapter. It should be a Nikon F Mount. I'm not sure how well it will work as it can depend on the flange distance so you might get some vignetting but its cheap enough to give it a try since you already have the camera. The adapters are only about $20. Realize you will have to shoot in Manual Settings and Manual Focus with them. If your Nikon lenses have aperture rings than you're okay.

As mentioned in comments many new Nikon Nikkor lenses don't have aperture rings anymore and unlike say Cannon will not stay open. So it depends on which lenses you've got. Third party lenses might still have aperture rings. Nikkor lenses from even a few years ago may as well.

Comment: Most contemporary Nikon lenses don't have an aperture ring and this will be especially true for a lens that have been used with a D3200. Setting an aperture value while it's on camera will have no effect since it will spring back to fully closed once the lens is unmounted.

Comment: @KamenMinkov that assumes its a NIkkor lens. They could be using Tamron, Sigma, or any number. But you are correct most Nikkor lenses don't have aperture rings anymore and won't stay open.

Comment: @MichaelClark pretty much any Rokinon/Samyang has aperture ring. Nikon D lenses that can still be pretty readily bought have aperture rings. Venus Optics all have aperture rings. Zeiss Milvus and Distagon have aperture rings. Can of course buy some Nikkor AI-S lenses still brand new with aperture rings. Some Sigma lenses have aperture rings. Any one of these will work just fine on OP's Sony.

Comment: @MichaelClark ahh edited out that paragraph if you want to clean up comments